# Unable to serve static content "images" on the server - nginx ubuntu

Tags: angular, nginx

I am trying to serve the images from a location on my server rather than having them under my deployment directory i.e. where my application is deployed.

I have my app base deployed at `/opt/myapp`
I created a folder `/opt/myapp-images` and put all the images under it. The full path is like `/opt/myapp-images/assets/images/folder1/fruit.png` and there are different folders under images.

I am able to access the path till `/opt/myapp-images/assets/images/folder1/` and see the image present there in browser but if I click on the image, it displays `404 error`.

Tried many things but none seems to work.

Following is my `nginx` conf file -

```
root /opt/myapp/dist/browser;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri @backend;
}

location /assets/images {
        autoindex on;
        alias  /opt/myapp-images/assets/images;
       } 

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
          expires 7d;
      }
```

In my html, I have path like `"src="/assets/images/folder1/fruit.png"`

Not sure what am I doing wrong. If any other information is required, please lemme know.

Comment: Do you have any other `location` blocks in your configuration? Maybe a *regular expression* `location` that matches any URI ending with `.png`?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, there is one related to cache. I updated in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx chooses one `location` to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). Currently, any URI ending with `.png` is processed by the last `location` block, which has the wrong document root for URIs beginning with `/assets/images`.

Use the `^~` modifier to make the prefix `location` take precedence over the *regular expression* locations. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /assets/images {
    autoindex on;
    root /opt/myapp-images;
    expires 7d;
}
```

Add the `expires` directive here, if it also applies to these URIs.

It is preferable to use `root` instead of `alias` if you can. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try it and keep you posted.

Comment: @Richard Smith, it seems to work. Just observing for a while. There is another thing related to it I need your help with. I am able to open the app and click on gallery menu and it opens the page fine. But if I click open in new tab or straightaway open the page like `https://myapp/gallery`, it displays `504 Gateway Time-out`. There is session timeout or anything. I believe it's the same config file may be? Any suggestions on this please? I will accept the answer anyway. For this issue, if a new question is required please lemme know. Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: You should post this as a new question, and include any relevant access and error log entries. If this is server is deployed in a business environment, consider posting the question on ServerFault.

Comment: @Richard Smith, sure mate. Will do. Thanks again.